# How to split strings with delimiters into a set?

Tags: python, regex, string, io, set

I want to read words from a file into a set like this:

```
# Text file
bill
beep-boop
wow
apostrophe'
```

Then when I print

```
>>> print(mySet)
{'bill', 'beep', 'boop', 'wow', 'apostrophe'}
```

So I don't want any leading or ending apostrophes either, but how can I have multiple delimiters with the `split()` function? All I have is this:

```
mySet = set((stdin.read().split()))
```

Comment: What delimiters do you have exactly?

Comment: @BradSolomon A word is one or more case insensitive characters. The characters can be all letters of the English language and or a single-quote/apostrophe. No decimal digits. No leading or ending apostrophes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than focusing on delimiters, you could focus instead on what constitutes a word/token.  From your comments,

> - A word is one or more case insensitive characters. The characters can be all letters of the English language and or a single-quote/apostrophe. No decimal digits. No leading or ending apostrophes.
> - 'Some99' would not be considered a word and should not be put into the set. Same goes for 'w3rd'.
> - If there are 2 words 'He' & 'he'--I only want the lowercase version.

Here's a tokenizer that encapsulates that:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\b[A-Za-z\'"]+\b', flags=re.U)
```

An example text file:

```
bill
beep-boop
wow
apostrophe'
a
bb
a?c?d?
abcd-abcd?
J'aime
I'm
He said, "Yep"
Some99\words\here\\
One more w3rd
```

can be read as:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = set(word.lower() for word in regex.findall(f.read()))

text
# {'d', 'a', 'said', 'abcd', 'apostrophe', 'beep', 'bb', 'c', 'more', 'he', 'words', "i'm", 'yep', 'bill', "j'aime", 'one', 'wow', 'here', 'boop'}
```

This is similar to the regex used by some machine learning algorithms to convert text documents to a matrix of token counts.  scikit-learn's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) uses `token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`, which defines words as having two or more letters.

To run this from the command line, create a script called `tokenizer.py`:

```
# tokenizer.py

import re
import sys

regex = re.compile(r'\b[A-Za-z\'"]+\b', flags=re.U)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = sys.argv[1]
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        text = set([word.lower() for word in regex.findall(f.read())])
    print(text)
```

Then you can run this from the command line like so:

```
 $ python3 tokenizer.py textfile.txt
```

You can experiment with this [here](https://regexr.com/3jfv5).

Comment: Your regex is not matching with "J'aime" and "I'm".

Comment: Sorry actually those should be 1 word. For example in `Don't` The apostrophe falls under `the character can be all English letters AND/OR an apostrophe.` Only leading and ending apostrophes should be removed. So it should be in the list as: `{'Some', 'Other', 'Words', 'Don't'}`

Comment: Yeah so if there are 2 words in the text file: `He` & `he` I only want the lowercase version. @BradSolomon P.S. Thanks a bunch for the help :)

Comment: @BradSolomon `Some99` would not be considered a word and should not be put into mySet. Same goes for `w3rd`

Comment: @Coder117 That's my last update.  Time for some research of your own if needed.  Good luck!